# Mostrar fechas no registradas - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema en una mejora a un sistema de asistencia. Tengo una tabla Asistencia la cual registra todas las marcaciones de los empleados (Tanto entrada, salida, FechadeAsistencia, etc) Esta tabla al consultarla pues muestra las marcaciones del día a día.

Lo que quiero es mostrar todos los días correlativos y si no hubiera marca del día pues que lo complete con NULL, es decir que supongamos tengo marcas del 02 de noviembre al 10 de noviembre, pero en ese intervalo la persona no marco el 03, 04, pues esos dias ponerlos en NULL.

He estado intentando y he llegado a esto:

Cree una tabla Temporal llamada #Nums:

```
`IF OBJECT_ID('#Nums', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Nums;
 CREATE TABLE #Nums(n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
 DECLARE @max AS INT, @rc AS INT;
 SET @max = 35;
 SET @rc = 1;
 INSERT INTO #Nums VALUES(0);
 WHILE @rc * 2 <= @max
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #Nums SELECT n + @rc FROM #Nums;
 SET @rc = @rc * 2;
 END
 INSERT INTO #Nums
 SELECT n + @rc FROM #Nums WHERE n + @rc <= @max;`
```

(Con esta tabla lo que hago es que me ayuda a completar los días en correlativo)

Posteriormente creo una segunda tabla Temporal llamada tmpNum:

```
`declare @ini datetime;
 declare @fin datetime;
 create table #tmpNum (Inicio datetime, Final datetime, idEmpleado int);
 SELECT @ini = MIN(FechaAsistencia), @fin = MAX(FechaAsistencia)
 FROM dbo.Asistencia where
 MONTH(FechaAsistencia) = 11 AND
 YEAR(FechaAsistencia) = 2022`
```

(Con esta tabla lo que hago es que me pueda dar el intervalo de dias en este caso el mes de noviembre del año 2022, lo cual me arroja del 01 al 30 de noviembre)

```
INSERT INTO #tmpNum values (@ini, @fin, 118);
```

(Con este INSERT lo que hago es llenar los campos correspondientes a Inicio,Final y idEmpleado, en este caso con el empleado con el id 118)

Ahora creo una tercera tabla temporal llamada #TablaTemporal

```
`SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT DATEADD(DAY, #Nums.n, #tmpNum.Inicio) AS Lasfechas, #tmpNum.idEmpleado
 INTO #TablaTemporal
 FROM #Nums INNER JOIN #tmpNum ON DATEADD(DAY, #Nums.n, #tmpNum.Inicio) <= #tmpNum.Final
 WHERE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, #Nums.n, #tmpNum.Inicio)) IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) ORDER BY         Lasfechas`
```

(Esto es para que pueda visualizar todas las fechas del 01 a 30 de noviembre menos los días domingos, que es lo que quiero mostrar)

Esto es lo que muestra:
Lasfechas          idEmpleado
`2022-11-01 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-02 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-03 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-04 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-05 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-07 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-08 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-09 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-10 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-11 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-12 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-14 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-15 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-16 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-17 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-18 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-19 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-21 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-22 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-23 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-24 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-25 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-26 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-28 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-29 00:00:00.000 118 2022-11-30 00:00:00.000 118`

Con estos datos lo que estaba pensando hacer es un LEFT OUTER JOIN entre la #TablaTemporal y la tabla Asistencia para que pueda mostrarme lo que quiero, pero no he podido llegar a lo que quiero.

```
select * from #TablaTemporal T LEFT JOIN Asistencia A ON T.Lasfechas = A.FechaAsistencia   ORDER BY T.Lasfechas;
```

Alguien sabe que mas puedo hacer en el LEFT JOIN para que pueda mostrar lo que quiero que es poner todas las marcas de la persona y las marcas que no tenga lo pueda poner en NULL?

Agradezco su ayuda y aclarar que soy nuevo en esto y es a lo que he podido llegar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente (algo parecido a lo que ya tienes):

Primero usemos la base que tienes de obtener un calendario mensual, para eso puedes crear un script, pero esta es una opción:

```sql
create table #calendario_temp (fecha datetime)
  
declare @desde datetime, 
        @hasta datetime 
  
set @desde = '2022-11-01'
SET @hasta = dateadd(day, 29, @desde)

while @desde <= @hasta begin 

  insert #calendario_temp(fecha)
  select @desde 

  set @desde = dateadd(day,1,@desde)
end
```

No hace falta explicar el script anterior, solamente toma una fecha inicio (la del mes de noviembre en este caso) y se setea la fecha HASTA para obtener un límite y como noviembre tiene 30 días, le coloco +29. En este punto ya tenemos el calendario, lo que queda por hacer es:

```sql
-- con esto creo una temporal de las fechas que asistí: 
-- (en este caso dos veces): 

select *
into #asistencias
from(
values('2022-11-01'),
      ('2022-11-10')
)x(fecha)

select calendar.fecha, 
       case when asis.fecha is null then 'No asistió' else 'Asistió' end Asistencia
from #calendario_temp calendar
     left join #asistencias asis on calendar.fecha = asis.fecha
```

Con lo último haces un `LEFT JOIN` (es lo mismo que LEFT OUTER JOIN) y con un `CASE...WHEN` creas una columna para saber cuándo asistió y cuando no, en mi caso coloqué flags, si deseas colocarle `NULL` también podrías.

- Esta es la `DEMO`: https://dbfiddle.uk/xGoLFr3z

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ayuda poder solucionar mi problema :D